# Why am I not seeing an error message?

Tags: php

I'm feeling my way around php for the first time in years. I'm trying to perform a simple select statement. I've confirmed the statement works directly against mysql. My php does not complete. I'd like to know why my real_query isn't working, I'd also like to know how to coax an error message out of this scenario. Here's the code:

```
function getRoot($nid)
{
    echo $nid; //displays 0
    try 
    {
        echo "Hello?"; //This displays

        //Why doesn't this work?!
        if($mysqli->real_query("SELECT * FROM gem, bundles WHERE gem.nid = bundles.baseNid AND bundles.nid = " . $nid))
        {
            echo "dafuq?"; //does not display
        }
        else
        {
            echo "foo"; //doesn't display
            echo $mysqli->error; //doesn't display
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo "Tralalalala"; //doesn't display
    }
    echo "teeheehee"; //doesn't display
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you have `error_reporting` enabled and `display_errors` on in your php.ini? (Assuming it's a development machine, set error_reporting to E_ALL|E_STRICT and display_errors to On).

Comment: Where is `$mysqli` defined?

Comment: apparently,either its not the right way or you are having an eye sight problem.. o btw, i learnt to think global when i started php.. :D

Comment: @Maerlyn That was the problem with coaxing the error out, thanks.

Comment: @cweiske Half of it is a duplicate, however the source of my issue was a problem with variable scoping. That's probably a duplicate of something too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `$mysqli` variable declared in the function, so your code produce a `FATAL ERROR` - you are calling a method of a non-object. if `$mysqli` is a global variable, you have to add `global $mysqli;` in the beginning of the function

Comment: +1 but why there is no $_mysqli!! that would have made things easier

Answer (score 4):

`$mysqli` is not defined in the function, and PHP throws a fatal error, which is **not** catcheable using standard exceptions.

You need to enable error reporting (display_errors set to On in php.ini, or through ini_set, eg: `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` );